# Textfile into MySQL database using command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-prompt

I currently have a textfile (.txt) with a random word on each row. Is it possible, to put every single line, into a MySQL database, and preform a particular PHP command when the word(s) are being inserted?

Example would be, to put the word "Hello" into the database, and have two columns, "Word" and "MD5". I know this can be done using pure PHP (reading the file with a php script, and running it in a loop) but this seems to take "forever" ... Would it be faster, doing it directly from PHP/MySQL command line?

I'm on Windows 8, using XAMPP.

The script I've tried (as said above) looks like this,

```
    $handle = fopen("randomWords.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $words = new Words;
            $words->word = $line;
            $words->md5 = md5($line);
            $words->save();
            set_time_limit(10);
        }
    } else {
        return 'File could not open';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figure this out myself, using sql command line.

```
load data local infile 'words.txt' into table words (@word) set word=@word, md5=md5(@word);
```